# c++ segmentation fault in linkedlist

Tags: c++

I created a program for my homework that deals with linked lists. It ran fine before i entered a number and then it crashed on me giving me a segmentation fault error. 
I know what that means but i cannot find the the issue.

Take a look and see if you could help me out! Thanks!

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node //node structure
{
    int number;
    node *next;

};

bool isempty(node *head);
char menu();
void first(node *&head, node *&last, int number );
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, int number);
void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
void shownode(node *current);

bool isempty(node *head)
{
    if(head = NULL)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;

}
char menu()
{
   char choice;
   cout<<"choose and option:"<<endl;
   cout<<"1. Add Node."<<endl;
   cout<<"2. Remove Node."<<endl;
   cout<<"3. Show Node List."<<endl;
   cout<<"4. Exit Program."<<endl;

cin>>choice;
return choice;


}
void first(node *&head, node *&last, int number ) //adding first
{
    node *temp =new node;
    temp->number = number;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;

}
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, int number)//adding more
{
    if(isempty(head))
        first(head, last, number);
    else 
    {
    node *temp =new node;
    temp->number = number;
    temp->next = NULL;  
    last->next = temp;
    last = temp;
    }
}
void remove(node *&head, node *&last)//destructor
{
    if(isempty(head))
        cout<<"List is empty."<<endl;
    else if (head == last)
    {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;

    }
    else 
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;


    }

}
void shownode(node *current)
{
    if (isempty(current))
        cout<<"list is empty"<<endl;

    else 
    {
        cout<<"Nodes in list:"<<endl;
        while(current != NULL)
        {

            cout<<current->number<<endl;
            current = current->next;

        }

    }

}
int main()
{
  node *head = NULL;  
  node *last = NULL;
  char choice;
  int number;

  do{
      choice = menu();

      switch(choice)
      {
          case '1': cout<<"inert number:"<<endl;
                  cin>>number;
          insert(head, last, number);
          break;
          case '2': remove(head, last);
          break;
          case '3': shownode(head);
          break;
          default: cout<<"Exit";


      }
  }while(choice != '4');


    return 0;
}
```

This is the error i got:

choose and option:
1. Add Node.
2. Remove Node.
3. Show Node List.
4. Exit Program.
1
inert number:
44

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault: 11; real time: 2s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: Run the program under a debugger. It will tell you what line the fault occurred on. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2):

First, this line of code,

```
if(head = NULL)
```

should be,

```
if(head == NULL)
```

Comment: Well, i feel stupid. That fixed it perfectly! Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes to catch the errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No idea if you are misunderstanding '=' and '==', '=' for assign value and '==' judge if equal.
In bool `isempty(node *head)` function
`if(head = NULL)` => `if (head == NULL)`

In `remove(node *&head, node *&last)` function

```
else if (head == last)
    {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;

    }
```

should be

```
else if (head == last)
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;

    }
```